# Confusing Mono Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono, owin, claims-based-identity

I decided to test the waters on using Xamarin Studio on my Mac to see how Xamarin have got on improving since Microsoft have been lending a hand. It was all going amazingly well, I even got EF working with MySql and a huge chunk of the site Im writing working. That was until I had to implement OWIN and the ASP.NET identity bits for logging users in. The code doesn't error and compiles but I get this rather generic Mono error. Can anyone shed any light on it? I've googled about but can't find anything (other than the source code for Mono with the string constant which appears in the error). I'm guessing Mono just can't handle one of the DLL's required to do Owin and Asp.NET Identity...

> System.ExecutionEngineException
>
> MonoError reused after mono_error_cleanup
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>   Details: Non-web exception.
>   Exception stack trace:
>     at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
>     at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/Assembly.cs:405 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.FilterTypesInAssemblies (System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager, System.Predicate`1[T] predicate) [0x00033] in <cc73190bab9d435c831510ff295c572a>:0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.TypeCacheUtil.GetFilteredTypesFromAssemblies (System.String cacheName, System.Predicate`1[T] predicate, System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager) [0x00015] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerTypeCache.EnsureInitialized (System.Web.Mvc.IBuildManager buildManager) [0x0002b] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerTypeWithinNamespaces (System.Web.Routing.RouteBase route, System.String controllerName, System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[T] namespaces) [0x0000c] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerType (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String controllerName) [0x0010a] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.System.Web.Mvc.IControllerFactory.GetControllerSessionBehavior (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, System.String controllerName) [0x00026] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetSessionStateBehavior (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) [0x00043] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) [0x00006] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler.System.Web.Routing.IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.PostResolveRequestCache (System.Web.HttpContextBase context) [0x00060] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Web/Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:85 
>     at System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule.OnApplicationPostResolveRequestCache (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00013] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/System.Web/Routing/UrlRoutingModule.cs:48 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () [0x001ba] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1030 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication+c__Iterator1.MoveNext () [0x006f3] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:1238 
>     at System.Web.HttpApplication.Tick () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web/HttpApplication.cs:927